# How to merge different document types and show as stack in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Suppose in .NET (don't care what language) I want to show a user a PDF, Word and Excel file together. I am trying to replicate a document process where a user might have a PDF file and he would like to attach a WORD file and an Excel file let's say to make a stack of documents (that I would save in some directory). Then he would like to click on a button and see a stack of these documents in 1 application of some sort.

How can I display the stack of documents WITHOUT first opening WORD, then openinig EXCEL and then openining ADOBE ACROBAT - this would be really annoying for the user. I would like one unified application or some idea to mimic one in .NET that can just show all 3 documents as if they were printed one after the other on paper. (I hope I am explaining this clearly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of to do this would be to leverage some sort of PDF conversion process to create one PDF file containing all three of these documents in "printed" (page-by-page) form, and then show that. The one application I can think of that could show all of these files is a web browser with appropriate Office and Acrobat viewer plugins, and you might find it difficult to leverage that, as browser preference and other user OS settings can cause various strategies for application launching to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the documents in PDF and develop a pdf viewer inside your application.
I would use a ready made library for that, don't reinvent the wheel. 
For example: http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/products/quickpdf/index.php